# How to control Rest Assured's logging filters through log4j2.xml?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, rest-assured

I want to redirect `RestAssured 5.3.0` logging to `log4j2` and be able to control the logging from `log4j2.xml` config.

My App example:

```
package org.example;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.filter.log.RequestLoggingFilter;
import io.restassured.filter.log.ResponseLoggingFilter;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.io.IoBuilder;

public class App {

    static {
        var logStream = IoBuilder.forLogger(RestAssured.class).buildPrintStream();

        var requestFilter = new RequestLoggingFilter(logStream);
        var responseFilter = new ResponseLoggingFilter(logStream);

        RestAssured.filters(requestFilter, responseFilter);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RestAssured.given().get("https://httpbin.org/");
    }
}
```

My `log4j2.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" strict="true">

    <Appenders>
        <Appender type="Console" name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{3} - %msg%n"/>
        </Appender>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>

        <Logger name="io.restassured" level="OFF"/>

    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Output:

```
13:25:43.198 [main] OFF   io.restassured.RestAssured - Request method:  GET
13:25:43.200 [main] OFF   io.restassured.RestAssured - Request URI: https://httpbin.org/
13:25:43.200 [main] OFF   io.restassured.RestAssured - Proxy:           <none>
13:25:43.200 [main] OFF   io.restassured.RestAssured - Request params:  <none>
```

1. Is this the correct approach for redirecting RestAssured logging to log4j2?
2. Why logs still show but with level `OFF`? Actually the logs show with whatever level I set for the `io.restassured` logger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't specify a logging level in `IoBuilder`, the log events are issued with the **configured** logging event (`OFF`). You just need to call `setLevel`:

```java
IoBuilder.forLogger(RestAssured.class).setLevel(Level.DEBUG).buildPrintStream();
```

**Remark**: IMHO using `IoBuilder` is never the best approach if you have other choices: you don't control where each log event ends. In your case, you could write a [`Filter`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/latest/io/restassured/filter/Filter.html) that calls the Log4j API directly.

Comment: Seems that I misunderstood that little detail. I thought that `RestAssured` sends the log events at level specified by them and setting the level of the PrintStream by me is not needed.

Thank you!